# Can't create Android App without Compatibility library?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-compatibility

I'm trying to create a small Android App, without the compatibility library for fragments and stuff. Just a simple app. When I get to the "install dependencies" step in Eclipse, the next and Finish are greyed out. How do I continue? Are all new apps really required to have compatibility library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway you can delete the compatibility library later in Eclipse from your project's `libs` folder and remove it from `Build Path`.

Why to do that though?

Comment: Yeah, why require a compatibility package for a phone-targeted app without fragments?

Comment: @NoBugs so you can use Fragments even with Android 2.x. If you don't want to then remove the compatibility jar. They do not have such option in the Wizard because everyone would want to use Fragments

Comment: Everyone wants to use fragments? I haven't really noticed them in 2.2/2.3 apps. Though it looks like they show up as separate activity in those versions?